# Unsafe c# code to speed up execution

Tags: c#

I have code that executes slowly, that I want to speed up through unsafe byte pointer mapped into a long.

The code I want to speed up reads:

```
public ulong seek(ulong ul)
{
    ulong v = table[ul >> 56, ul >> 48 & 0xFF] ^ table2[ul >> 40 & 0xFF ul >> 32 &
    0xFF] ^ table[ul >> 24 & 0xFF, ul >> 16 & 0xFF] ^ table2[ul >> 8 & 0xFF, ul &
    0xFF];
    return v;
}
```

In this code "table" and "table2" are each 256 x 256 tables with random ulong values in them. I would want to modify the above by adding:

```
v2 = /* Add code to compute the same value using unsafe method, byte pointer arithmetic into the ulong "ul" instead of whole bunch of shifting.*/

Console.WriteLine("Called seek, v={0:X16}, v2={1:X16},
                     result={2}",v, v2, v==v2 ? "Pass" : "Fail"
                 );
```

This way, I can test that both methods are returning the same value, by calling this function repeatedly with random values

Answer (score 1):

If you are in unsafe context you can indeed get rid of the bit-shifting:

These two statements are equal in value:

```
  var a = (ul >> 48) & 255;
  var b = ((byte*) &ul)[6];
```

And if you put a break point in the code and go to disassembly you'll see that although the second line looks complicated, it is not complicated at all, you can't get any faster!

```
var a = (ul >> 48) & 255;
  0000007e  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+20h] 
  00000083  sar         rax,30h 
  00000087  and         rax,0FFh 
  0000008d  mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],rax 
var b = ((byte*) &ul)[6];
  00000092  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rsp+26h] 
  00000097  mov         byte ptr [rsp+30h],al
```

And second, indexing an array is slow. Typically, instead of:

```
var sum = 0;
for ( var i = 0 ; i < barr.Length ; i++ )
    sum += barr[i];
```

You can instead do:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* pb = barr)
    {
        for ( var i = 0 ; i < barr.Length ; i++ )
            sum += pb[i];
    }
}
```

And then I assume that your "table" is not a byte array but instead an array of ulongs? Then you can of course cast that into a byte array as well:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (ulong* ptable = table)
    {
        var pbtable = (byte*)ptable;
        //now you can access table as if it were a byte array
    }
}
```

All this is typically seen when working with image processing, where you use .LockBits on a bitmap to get a pointer to the bits for really fast processing.

Comment: Are you sure that code is faster? On my machine they both appear to be identical in terms of speeds. Here is the code I used to test it: http://pastebin.com/XgjJfyc7

Comment: @John Smith - Indeed, this post is incorrect. Indexing an array is NOT really slow. in fact using Unsafe code here might even bring more performance problems since it has to pin the array each time which is bad for the performance of the GC. Now, indexing an Array CAN be slower if it's in a checked scope. This however is by default disabled for Release Mode so only in Debug Mode would you have performance differences

Comment: Well, I did try your code and on my machine (Win7 64 + VS64, release mode) and I get twice the speed out of the unsafe code. And when I change barr into a *two dimensional array* as in the OP's case, I it runs four times as fast. But I do acknowledge the fact that it can only be used when looping over large arrays and not just within a function like the one the OP have. Instead, the whole function must be made unsafe and a pointer passed.

Comment: That's rather strange. Even in release code they both run at the same speeds for me. Not sure what's going on (perhaps the compiler doing optimizations?)

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend that you use c/c++ and DllImport the methods that have that kind of processing.  Don't forget to PIN your pointers before calling those methods.

Some background:

I work extensively with audio and video.  In development, first I create an algorithm that works (safe code, indexes into byte[], and so on).  Then, my first optimization is to move to pointers and unsafe code, with which i get from about 30 to 50% speed improvement, no more.  Then, when everything is settled down from the algorithm and architecture point of view, I re-code that into the c or c++ code and call it using DllImports.  I'll left the speed improvement index for you to try it, in this case, but sometimes I got over 10x speed improvement.

Comment: I'm curious why you choose DllImport instead of writning it in C++/CLI. That would bring you the best of both worlds?

Comment: I hate to see the sight of c++/CLI - so it's just a personal preference.  All those ::'s make me dizzy.  I actually have one project (mp3 player) which was written as a CLI wrapper around a legacy code - and I would still use that for wrapping up classes, but for simple loops, I guess that's overkill.